# How to access instance variables when interpolating message in Hibernate Validator?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I am using Hibernate Validator with Spring to validate object when inserting it into repository with `CrudRepository::save`. Let's say we have class:

```java
public class Person {
  public int id;

  @NotBlank(message="User with id: ${id} is missing name")
  public String name;

}
```

I want the interpolated message to access all fields of the Person instance e.g. id field and then access them like "${id}" or "${this.id}". [Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/8.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-interpolation-with-message-expressions) mentions something about being able to access all bean properties but I guess it can only be used with class-level constraints.

Is there some way to do this without resorting to using class-level constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constraint validator cannot access any info outside the field itself. So, in other words, there's no way to access sibling fields. This is related to the scope of a constraint. Look at it this way:

```java
@NotBlank
public String name;
```

A not blank `name` can be a field in person, or it can be a field in the company, or some other class. It makes no difference to `@NotBlank` where it is located.

Hence as you've suggested in your question, to get access to other class fields when interpolating the message the constraint should be at a class level...
To not create a lot of custom constraints, you might consider looking at a [`@ScriptAssert`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-defineconstraints-hv-constraints).

Also note that `ConstraintViolationException` contains a list of `ConstraintViolation` in it and from it you should be able to get access to a leaf bean (`getLeafBean()`) or to root bean (`getRootBean()`), and get the info you need after the exception was thrown.

Comment: see also this somewhat related discussion https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/how-can-i-get-the-root-bean-in-a-custom-validator-when-using-field-level-constraints-field-access-strategy/6949